# Multiplication of value not working on output field

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to make an output field multiply it's value based on a value I set in my input field. eg. if the input field is equal to 2 then the output field must equal to 2 * the existing value the output field(Initially output field has a value that is set based on the currency that is chosen). My code will explain better and I have created a stackblitz to demo it.

Here is my stckblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-f1drwx?file=src/app/app.component.ts

*HTML*

```
<mat-card class="card">    
<mat-form-field class="form-field" appearance="outline">
<mat-label> Input Currency </mat-label>
<input
  matInput
  type="number"
  required
  [(ngModel)]="inputCurrencyValue"
  (keyup)="onUpdate($event)"
  (change)="onUpdate($event)"
/>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
<mat-select (selectionChange)="onInputSelectChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedInput" disabled> 
  <mat-option [value]="selectedInput">{{selectedInput[0]}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field class="form-field" appearance="outline">
<mat-label> Output Currency </mat-label>
<input
  matInput
  type="number"
  disabled
  [(ngModel)]="outputCurrencyValue"
/>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
<mat-select (selectionChange)="onOutputSelectChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedOutput">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let item of currenciesArr" [value]="item[1]">{{item[0]}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
</mat-card>
```

*TS*

```
  public currencies: any;
  public currenciesArr: any;
  inputCurrencyValue: number = 0;
  outputCurrencyValue: number = 0;
  selectedInput = [];
  selectedOutput = [];

  getCurrencies() {
    this.currencies = this.currencyService.currencyRates();
    this.currenciesArr = Object.keys(this.currencies.rates).map((key) => [
      String(key),
      this.currencies.rates[key],
    ]);
    this.selectedInput = this.currenciesArr.find((o) => o[0] === 'EUR');
    this.selectedOutput = this.currenciesArr.find((o) => o[0]);
    console.log(this.selectedOutput);
  }

  onUpdate(event) {
    this.inputCurrencyValue = event.target.value;
  }
  onInputSelectChange(event) {
    this.inputCurrencyValue = event.value;
  }
  onOutputSelectChange(event) {
    this.outputCurrencyValue = event.value;
  }
```

So what I am struggling with is to make the output field reflect the multiplied values after it already has a value. Also if the currency is changed then I need to show the multiplied value.

Comment: So you want the output currency field to display the input currency field value * the selected currency rate whenever the input gets changed?

Comment: @kyleruss yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ts Add a `selectedOutputCurrency` variable to keep track of the selected output currency rate

```
  selectedOutputCurrency: number = 0;
```

Have your select update event handler set this currency rate on select

```
  onOutputSelectChange(event) {
    this.selectedOutputCurrency = event.value;
  }
```

And on your input change event handler multiply the input by the selected currency rate

```
  onUpdate(event) {
    this.inputCurrencyValue = event.target.value;

    this.outputCurrencyValue = this.inputCurrencyValue * this.selectedOutputCurrency;
  }
```

Similar logic can be used for the reverse when changing the output currency